# PDE with solution in $H^1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

We have $\Omega = (0,1)$ and  $\int_{\Omega} e^x u' v' = \int_{\Omega} fv $

$\forall v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$

What is $u \in H^1_0(\Omega)$ if $f=1$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using integration by part to get 
$$\int_0^1 ({\left( {{e^x}u(x)} \right)} '- 1)v(x)dx = 0$$
for all $v$ in $H_0^1(0,1)$, therefore you just have  to solve 
$$(e^{x}u'(x))'=1$$
with Dirichlet boundary condition

Comment: Ahhh  perfect, thanks a lot for your answer! So the solution will be $-c_1 e^{-x} + c_2 - e^{-x}x $. 
I have another question: How can I discretize my initial equation with $ S = S_{G, 0}^{1,0}$ where $G:= \{r_i : 0 \leq i \leq n \}$ with $r_i = [x_i, x_{i+1}]$ and $h = \frac{1}{n+1} $ and $x_i = ih $ for $ 0 \leq i \leq n+1$ ?

Comment: For the finite differences scheme it is standard, you can look at any book to understand the principle.